# JQuery Object [object Object] has no method 'slider' when trying to use the slider demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So im trying to use the slider demo (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) and i copy the code as so:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <style>
        #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,


    values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="demo">

<p>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Set the <code>range</code> option to true to capture a range of values with two drag handles.  The space between the handles is filled with a different background color to indicate those values are selected.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->


</body>
</html>
```

But the slider doesnt appear, and Chrome gives me this error: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'

Any ideas? I searched around but the fixes didnt seem to apply to me

Comment: you should load the [`jquery-ui.js`](http://jqueryui.com/download) plugin.

Comment: Oh thanks, now i see, i feel so stupid. Haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply because you didn't include the source code of jQuery UI Slider in your document.
"UI Core", "UI Widget" and "UI Mouse" are dependencies and you should include them in your document.
Just go to the [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) of JQuery UI website and download an appropriate version.(At least check "UI Core", "UI Widget", "UI Mouse" and "Slider"). When you extract content of downloaded file, you will find necessary scripts by their names.

Comment: At least provide a link or code sample to make it look like you're not stealing someones answer from the comments above

Comment: I deleted immediately when I saw that, I glossed over it.